# If sale price is 0 display list price else display both

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I am using Wp All Import plugin to import an XML with products in WordPress.

- WPAI URL:
  http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/if-statements/
- WooCommerce: https://docs.woocommerce.com/

I have this code here:

- **Regular price:**
  [IF({price_list[1][.!='0.00']})]{price_list[1]}[ELSE]{price_sale[1]}[ENDIF]
- **Sale price:** [IF({price_list[1][.!='0.00']})]{price_sale[1]}[ENDIF]

and the XML structure like this:

```
<price_sale>0.00</price_sale>
<price_list>84.00</price_list>
```

My problem is that the IF statements doesn't work. The price on the website is 0.00

What I want ?
I want to display both prices when I have them both in XML or to display only one if there is no discount.

Comment: `Regular price: [IF({price_list[0][.!='0.00']})]{price_list[0]}[ENDIF]`

Comment: The syntax is incorrect